# What is the best graph type to show a comparison value between two cases?

Tags: statistics, data

In that graph, I want to show the two values and the error percentage from the comparison between two values. I am using microsoft excel.

can anyone give me any idea which best graph for this case?
Thank you

Comment: If you really only have two values, I don't think a graph is necessary. Just the values themselves in a table + the error % should be sufficient.

Comment: but my professor want it in a graph instead,
I have four cases to be compared, but each case I want to compare the two values from measurement and analysis, have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, you probably want to use a bar chart combined with a line for the error. Have a look at [Create a combination chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-combination-chart-cf2c969a-b11e-4a62-bb8f-da021177452f) for more details.

In your case, and using dummy data, it would probably look something like this:

- Data in Excel

[image]

- Resulting combination graph

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand this graph, What I want is the information error percentage between two values for each case, but inside the graph it include 4 cases. 
I tried to make this graph, but it seems like the excel consider for all cases together..

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I understand now. I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. now I think you are very right... thank you so much!!! it is very helpful..